# Vue 1 -v-model does not support element type: DIV

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use this [plugin](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) for multiselect in my Vue 1 project.
I am using it in my component like it says in the docs to use it:

```
<v-select v-model="player.position" :options="['dm','rm']"></v-select>
```

But, I get this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: v-model does not support element type: DIV (found in component: <player-info>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The warning means you put a `v-model` on a `div` tag somewhere in your `<player-info>` component.

Comment: But, the error is only present when I have v-select component in the template, when I remove it, it is gone, and I am not having v-model on a div tag there

Comment: How are you registering the v-select component?

Comment: ```import vSelect from 'vue-select';
Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)```

Comment: And you're using `vue-select` version 1?

Comment: yes, that is correct